# jQuery loop through all h3 and selects on page and format output in textarea

Tags: jquery

So I have a basic structure of a page and my corresponding script:

```js
jQuery('select').change(function() {
  var abc = jQuery("select option:selected").text();
  var def = jQuery("h3").text();
  jQuery('textarea[name="ghi"]', $form).val(def + "\n\n" + abc).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Title</h3>
<select>
  <option value="A">This is Option a</option>
</select>

<h3>Title</h3>
<select>
  <option value="B">This is Option b</option>
</select>
```

This outputs each as

```
Title Title This is Option a This is Option b
```

Which I understand - but how do I get the textarea to output as

```
Title This is Option a
Title This is Option b
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: You have only one option in select and you are trying to do something on change? You are also missing textarea in your html code. and $form as well in your JS code

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you to be a [mcve]

Comment: Add wrap to your textarea too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes had to be made to the HTML as well as the JavaScript:

- Added `<option default>` to each `<select>` because having a select with only one option is pointless.
- Gave each `<option value='Title'>` which makes it easier to extract data from a single element like `<option value='val'>text</option>`

There were a few problems in OP code:

- `jQuery("h3").text()` will print both `h3`. So in the example there is specific jQuery methods used to pinpoint what is being accessed:

  ```
  // <option value="VALUE">...</option>
  $('select').first().find(':selected').val()

  // <option value="">TEXT</option>
  $('select').first().find(':selected').text()
  ```
- Rendering to `<textarea>` with text or setting the `.value` property doesn't have a way of inserting linebreaks (that I know of least -- go ahead and comment if the contrary). Rendering HTML to a `<textarea>` actually allows us to add `'&#10;'` for a linebreak.

  ```
   $('textarea').html(A + B)
  ```

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
  var A = $('select').first().find(':selected').val() + ' ' + $('select').first().find(':selected').text() + '&#10;';

  var B = $('select').last().find(':selected').val() + ' ' + $('select').last().find(':selected').text()

  $('textarea').html(A + B)
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

h3 {
  margin: 3px 0
}

h3:first-of-type {
  margin-top: -3px
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <select>
    <option default></option>
    <option value='Title'> This is Option a</option>
  </select>

  <h3>Title</h3>
  <select>
    <option default></option>
    <option value='Title'> This is Option b</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>

<textarea></textarea>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding `textarea` to your HTML and removing `change` event on select because it makes no sense this is working solution. You can use it for as many selects and H3s that you want.

```js
let abc = [];
let def = [];
$("select option:selected").each(function(el) {
  abc.push($(this).text())
});
$("h3").each(function(el) {
  def.push($(this).text())
});
for(let i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
  let text = $('textarea[name="ghi"]').val();
  $('textarea[name="ghi"]').val(text + def[i] + ' ' + abc[i] + '\n').change();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Title</h3>
<select><option value="A">This is Option a</option></select>

<h3>Title</h3>
<select><option value="B">This is Option b</option></select>
<textarea name='ghi'></textarea>
```

And now this is solution with change event on select. But for this solution you will have to add at least one more option to both selects:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $('textarea[name="ghi"]').val('').change(); //setting text area to ''
  let abc = [];
  let def = [];
  $("select option:selected").each(function(el) {
    abc.push($(this).text())
  });
  $("h3").each(function(el) {
    def.push($(this).text())
  });
  for(let i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
    let text = $('textarea[name="ghi"]').val();
    $('textarea[name="ghi"]').val(text + def[i] + ' ' + abc[i] + '\n').change();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Title</h3>
<select>
  <option value="A">This is Option a</option>
  <option value="B">This is Option b</option>
</select>

<h3>Title</h3>
<select>
  <option value="A">This is Option a</option>
  <option value="B">This is Option b</option>

</select>
<textarea name='ghi'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

vi,
Here is how I solved your question,
First, I have gotten all H3 and Selected options then I added each H3(s) as a title

Title
This is option A
Title
This is option B

here is my sample code

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    var h3s = $('h3').each(function(value) {
        value + "\n";
    });

    var options = $('select option:selected').each(function(value) {
        value + "\n";
    });

    var output = "";
    $(h3s).each(function(i, value) {
        console.log("Index: " + i + " value: " + value.innerText + "\n" + options[i].innerText);
        output += value.innerText + "\n" + options[i].innerText + "\n";
    });

    $('body').append($('<textarea>', {
        name: 'ghi'
    }).val(output));

});
```

Please let me know if I have solved your question.